# Why didn't Sauron give the Hobbits any rings?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In the movie *The Lord of the Rings* it said that Sauron somehow gave (presumably by proxy) several rings to Elves, Dwarves, and Men. There's also another race called Hobbits, who became quite important in the story. Why didn't he give them any rings so that he could control them as well?

Forgive my ignorance here; I never read the books and I'm only watching the movie for the 2nd time in 16 years.

Comment: @Adamant ok yea that sounds a little related I suppose. Though if I wanted to be the Stack Exchange equivalent of an attorney I could say that it has no accepted answer thus should not be marked as a dupe, but yea it's obviously a dupe. What shall I do? Delete and lose my upvote?? ;)

Comment: It’s only [tag:story-identification] questions that need accepted answers (on both) to be marked as duplicate. You don’t need to delete it (and indeed shouldn’t).

Comment: Oh ok I was really basing that comment on StackOverflow anyway OK ok I'll delete but you owe me an upvote my good friend

Comment: I think you misread Adamant's comment - he said you *shouldn't* delete :-) See also meta: [Is it encouraged to delete your own questions if they have possible duplicates?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7943/31394) TL;DR: a duplicate of a good question is often a good question in its own right.

Comment: @Randal'Thor  oh yes you are quite right on all fronts.